# How to know if someone visited website before using socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, web, socket.io, chat

I'm a beginner, I made a simple chat website where the first thing that's asked is a username then you're sent to a public chat room. But the problem is when reloading it always sends you back again to the username prompt. I want to know if the same user joined again so that he's brought firstly to the public chat if he reloads or opens the page again.

Comment: Use cookies, they're made for this! Does your app require and authentication?

Comment: Yep, cookies are the way! There are plenty of tutorials and example codes for it, a quick google search should do the trick. Try what you find and come back if you get stuck somewhere.

Comment: Your server will need to handle distributing cookies then on the client side, on connect, just send `document.cookie` and have the server handle the cookie and send back the session data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, since you're using Nodejs, you'll need to allow it to use cookies, add this to your index.js file (I assume you're using express):

```
app.use(express.cookieParser());
```

When the user goes to your page you set a cookie in their browser which acts as a key:

```
res.cookie('hasVisited', 'True')
```

So overall, when your page loads, within the endpoint of that page you could use this code to tell if they have visited before or not:

```
if(req.cookie.hasVisited){
   //User has visited this page before. Do whatever you want with this information, so redirect them to the public chat automatically
   res.redirect('/pageOfPublicChat');
}else{
   // User has not visted before, carry on as normal and set a cookie for next time they do
   res.cookie('hasVisited', 'True');
}
```